# C# Storing and filtering a list containing an array of doubles

Tags: c#, arrays, gis, latitude-longitude

I have series of doubles in the format of decimal latitude/longitude values. I want to store these values and when it comes to adding a new value to the list see if there is already a value in the list that is ±0.0001 to the latitude and then the longitude. If the value is withing ±0.0001 of either the latitude or the longitude I do not want to store it.

What I would like to recreate is a version of the MongoDB Geospatial $near command.

Can anyone please offer any advice on how to go about this? Are there any free c# geospatial libraries that would help me achieve this goal?

Many Thanks for the advice.

Comment: What if you have the numbers 0.0001, 0.00015, and 0.00021 and you happen to store 0.0001 first. Then you will have stored .0001 and .00021 when you could have just stored 0.00015. Isn't that a consideration? Perhaps you should store all values and filter on demand.

Comment: How many values do you need to store?

Comment: Would [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) do what you need?

Comment: @Justin I imagine that OP receives data stream from a GPS and doesn't want o store useless values if the device is not moving.

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to avoid duplicate lat/lon storage?  Using your algorithm, if your database has 0 deg lat and  0 deg lon, it will not store 0 deg lat, 80 deg lon which is a long ways away.

Comment: I have about ten thousand points in my dataset, I dont really want to store points where the device hasn't moved location.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any libraries, but you could use LINQ. Here's one for a `List<Tuple<double, double>>`:

```
var y = new Tuple<double, double>(15.25, 18.700001);

if(!coordinates.Any(x => Math.Abs(x.Item1 - y.Item1) <= 0.0001 || Math.Abs(x.Item2 - y.Item2) <= 0.0001)) {
    // No coordinate in the list is within ±0.0001 of either the latitude or the longitude
    coordinates.Add(y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, something like this should work for you, assuming the coordinates are wrapped in some kind of container.

```
public class Coordinates
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
public bool IsNear(List<Coordinates> coords, double lat, double lon, double tolerance)
{
    return coords.Any(p => Math.Abs(p.Latitude - lat) < tolerance || Math.Abs(p.Longitude - lon) < tolerance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate distance between two points:

```
if (Math.Abs(Math.Sqrt((longitude - longitude_before) * (longitude - longitude_before) + (latitude - latitude_before) * (latitude - latitude_before))) > 0.0001)
{
   // Record new point
}
```

where latitude_before and longitude_before are last entries in recorded path - it seems to me that it is not needed to check previous points. If it turns out that it is, and performance becames an issue, you will have to take a look at [range search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_searching).